# How to compile this function

Tags: compile

I want to compile my function that calculates the energy of a particle system. This is what I've tried:

```
n = 512;
nl = Ceiling[Power[n, (3)^-1]];
r = 1.;
σ = 2 r;
ρ = 0.01/((2 r)^3);
l = Power[n/ρ, (3)^-1];
ε = 1;
εr = .01;
z = 1;

v = Flatten[Table[l ({i, j, k} - .5)/(nl), {i, nl}, {j, nl}, {k, nl}], 2];
c = RandomSample[Join[Table[-1, {n/2}], Table[1, {n/2}]]];
tc = Times[#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2]]] &@Subsets[c, {2}];

UC = 
 Compile[{{vv, _Real, 2}}, 
  Total[(4 ε ((σ/#[[1]])^12 - (σ/#[[1]])^6) + 
       1/(4 π εr) (#[[2]] z)/#[[1]]) & /@ 
    Transpose[{Sqrt[Total[((#[[1]] - #[[2]]) - 
             l*Round[(#[[1]] - #[[2]])/l])^2]] & /@ Subsets[vv, {2}],
             tc
    }]
  ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]

UC[v]
```

However, the compilation of `UC` never finishes and after some time, the kernel becomes unresponsive and has to be killed. So I can't get the speed advantages of compilation. How can I persuade Mathematica to compile my function? I don't think the function is too complex to be compiled, there are only basic operations used.

Comment: Since you only try to compile some of your code, while referencing other uncompiled parts, this is probably not what you want, i.e. I don't think this will give you any benefits. Try to compile to WML instead of C, and use `CompilePrint ` to look at the compiled code. It calls the main evaluator almost everywhere.

Comment: You can look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) to see which built-in functions are compilable. Notice for instance that `Subsets` are not in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `Subsets` function. However, I can still put the `Subsets` part outside and the rest should compile.

Comment: Evaluate this ``System`SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True]`` and then try to compile your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem lies with the inclusion of `tc`, which in this case contains 130816 elements, in  `InlineExternalDefinitions`. This is apparently too much for Mathematica to handle, but it never complains about it. I'm not aware of any documented limitations of `InlineExternalDefinitions`, so users should take the appropriate precautions when including large amounts of data in compiled functions.

*Update*

Thanks to the helpful suggestions from @MariusLadegårdMeyer and @Sektor, I managed to rewrite the function so that it can be fully compiled except for the `Subsets` part. The compiled function runs about twice as fast as the solution provided by @MariusLadegårdMeyer, however in this case all variables need to be passed to the compiled function at runtime (not an issue):

```
UC2 = Compile[{{vs, _Real, 3}, {tc, _Real, 1}, {l, _Real}, {ε, _Real},
               {σ, _Real}, {εr, _Real}, {z, _Real}},
  Total[(4 ε ((σ/#[[1]])^12 - (σ/#[[1]])^6) + 
       1/(4 π εr) (#[[2]] z)/#[[1]]) &@{Sqrt[
      Total[Transpose[(((#[[1]] - #[[2]]) - 
              l*Round[(#[[1]] - #[[2]])/l])^2) &@Transpose[vs]]]], 
     tc}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
  ]
```

Speed comparison:

```
AbsoluteTiming[UC[Subsets[v, {2}], tc]] (*from @MariusLadegårdMeyer*)
```

> ```
> {0.207897, -75.0581}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming[UC2[Subsets[v, {2}], tc, l, ε, σ, εr, z]] (*my solution*)
```

> ```
> {0.096658, -75.0581}
> ```

Comment: It is probably the sheer size of the code to be compiled that causes a problem. You could try compiling without optimizations (i.e., common subexpression elimination) and see if that allows the process to finish. Alternatively, pass `Subsets[c, {2}]` and `Subsets[vv, {2}]` as parameters.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can you explain what you mean with "common subexpression elimination" and how to compile without it?

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would compile it. As Oleksandr R. commented, we want to inline everything except the huge lists.

```
UC = Compile[
  {{v, _Real, 3}, {tc, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{inner},
   inner =
    Sqrt[Total[((#[[1]] - #[[2]]) - 
           l*Round[(#[[1]] - #[[2]])/l])^2]] & /@ v;
   Total[4 ε ((σ/inner)^12 - (σ/
         inner)^6) + (tc z)/((4 π εr) inner)]
   ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
  ]
UC[Subsets[v,{2}],tc]
```

A crucial improvement that makes both compiled and uncompiled versions much faster is to apply the outer function to the full vectors `inner` and `tc`, instead of `Map`ing to each pair of elements.

Note however that since the values of `n`, `nl` etc. are "hard coded" at Compile-time, one would need to recompile if one changes any of the parameters that in turn can change `v` or `tc`. A way around this is, of course, to simply make all the parameters arguments to the compiled function.